# How to pick only specific values by looping through a column using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to use `openpyxl` to accomplish the below. I have multiple sheets with a column, say C, having values as given below and I need to pick only the last value from each block:

```
C


Student Fees
1223
3345
123

Student Fees
110
111
1111
345
-1923

Student Fees
267
4566
3456
```

So, my output should be like:

```
123
-1923
3456
```

I'm trying to do this with the below code:

```
for cell in WS['C']:
 if(cell.value is not None):
   if(str(cell.value == 'Student Fees'):
     print("{1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(-1,0).value)
```

I'm able to loop through the total column and print everything but I'm unable to figure out how to print only the necessary last values. How to accomplish this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by setting conditions that need to be met: an empty cell below a cell containing "Student Fees".

```
marker = False
for cell in ws['C']:
    if cell.value and if cell.value == "Student Fees":
        marker = True
    elif marker and if cell.value is None:
        print(cell.offset(row=-1).value)
        marker = False
```

Comment: I have multiple sheets and it works for majority of them but for some it throws ValueError. Any idea why it could be happening? The row index of -1 should not be problem right, because it's working for most sheets? What do you think?

Comment: You should always provide the traceback for errors but I suspect it's when you check for "Student Fees".

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the standards of Stackoverflow. I will remember that. The traceback is as follows:
 `File "marks.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(cell.offset(row=-1).value)
  File "/<the whoe path>/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 307, in offset` 
    `return self.parent.cell(column=offset_column, row=offset_row)
  File "/<the whole>/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 237, in cell`
    `raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1`

Comment: So you can't offset(row=-1) from the first row.

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense. But what surprises me is that it works for most sheets but for some it fails. I don't understand why it's able to find a `cell.offset(row=-1)` for some sheets but not for others. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Yes, if you are in the first row, the offset will give you row 0, which doesn't exist.